# Save Encrypted data in text file

Tags: encryption, text-files

I have encrypted my output data. I want to save that data in a file. When I am saving it in a text file, I believe it is not saved properly. Because, I can't get proper data after decryption from that file. I am using C#. Do I need to implement my own file format? Please help me.

Comment: Try posting some of your code. It's difficult to know why something does not work when we can't see the code.

Answer (score 0):

i belive it's Unnecessary to ask you if you tried encrypting / decrypting some simple string.

try using those methods for saving they are soo simple:

```
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText();
        System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes();
        System.IO.File.ReadAllText();
```